# Working with Ruby class: Capitalizing a string

Tags: ruby, string, capitalize

I'm trying to get my head around how to work with Classes in Ruby and would really appreciate some insight on this area. Currently, I've got a rather simple task to convert a string with the start of each word capitalized. For example:

```
Not Jaden-Cased: "How can mirrors be real if our eyes aren't real"
Jaden-Cased:     "How Can Mirrors Be Real If Our Eyes Aren't Real"
```

This is my code currently:

```
class String
  def toJadenCase
    split
    capitalize

  end
end

#=> usual case: split.map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
```

Output:

```
Expected: "The Moment That Truth Is Organized It Becomes A Lie.",
 instead got: "The moment that truth is organized it becomes a lie."
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking or what you're currently expecting. You currently `split` the string and throw away the results, then return capitalizing the string. Code that would actually work appears to be a comment below all of the code.

Comment: lol i thought I had to separate the methods when using Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you not pollute the core `String` class with the addition of an instance method. Instead, just add an argument to the method to hold the string. You can do that as follows, by downcasing the string then using `gsub` with a regular expression.

```
def to_jaden_case(str)
  str.downcase.gsub(/(?<=\A| )[a-z]/) { |c| c.upcase } 
end
```

```
to_jaden_case "The moMent      That trUth is organized, it becomes a lie."
  #=> "The Moment      That Truth Is Organized, It Becomes A Lie."
```

Ruby's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
(?<=\A| )  : use a positive lookbehind to assert that the following match
             is immediately preceded by the start of the string or a space 
[a-z]      : match a lowercase letter
```

`(?<=\A| )` can be replaced with the *negative lookbehind* `(?<![^ ])`, which asserts that the match is not preceded by a character other than a space.

Notice that by using [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) with a regular expression (unlike the *split*-process-*join* dance), extra spaces are preserved.

When spaces are to be matched by a regular expression one often sees whitespaces (`\s`) matched instead. Here, for example, `/(?<=\A|\s)[a-z]/` works fine, but sometimes matching whitespaces leads to problems, mainly because they also match newlines (`\n`) (as well as spaces, tabs and a few other characters). My advice is to match space characters if spaces are to be matched. If tabs are to be matched as well, use a character class (`[ \t]`).

Comment: Regex scares me right now =/, but it's inevitable I'm going to have to learn it at some point I guess

Comment: A wise man once said "There's nothing to fear but fear itself, and regular expressions.". Yes, it takes a bit of time to get comfortable with regexes, but in a sense they are a fairly simple computer language, with far few methods than most others. You mostly need the basics, up to and including capture groups, non-capture groups, postive and negative lookbehinds and lookaheads, and named captures. There are other features that are powerful, like `\K` and `\G`, but they can wait. Some coders find them fun, though that is sometimes related to a personality disorder.

Comment: Haha noted mate, I'll definitely put time aside and look into it!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 def toJadenCase
    self.split.map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
 end
```

Comment: don't need `self`, btw.

Comment: LOOL ffs I thought class worked differently but get it now, you just don't need to pass it to an argument because the argument is already created. Cheers mate